# Fitting json data in a single query string variable

Tags: javascript, json, query-string

I am writing a web application to exchange contact information fast via QR.
I use a QR api wich is formatted like this:

```
`http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=MyData&size=400x400`
```

I have json data formatted in a string, example of output:

```
`http://[myapp-url]/RecieveContact.html?Name=John%20Diggle&Title=IT%20Consultant&Organisation=testcomp&Telwork=0498553311&Telhome=&Gsm=0498553311&Email=testemail@mail.be&Website=www.testwebsite.be&Birthdate=24/04/97&Addresswork=&Addresshome=`
```

JSON data:

```
{"Name":"John Diggle",
"Title":"IT Consultant",
"Organisation":"testcomp",
"Telwork":"0498818587",
"Telhome":"",
"Gsm":"0498818587",
"Email":"testemail@mail.be",
"Website":"www.testwebsite.be",
"Birthdate":"24/04/97",
"Addresswork":"",
"Addresshome":""}
```

The problem is when you put this url in the QR generator it only recognises the `Name` parameter. I understand why this happens.

The question is is there a way using javascript to convert all this data in a string and convert it back on the recieving end?

Or does anyone know another potential fix for this problem?

Comment: All the data used in example output is fake Just putting this out there.

Comment: Try creating a json of the json. And decode it twice

Comment: Btw, I request you to kindly post the data in the question and not the URL

Comment: *"it only recognises the Name parameter. I understand why this happens."* – Please expand on that, because I *don't* understand it.

Comment: It only recognises that parameter because it is the only parameter with a "?" in the querystring the rest is "&" but the api also works with "&" this means the api thinks that data is for the api and not part of the data parameter

Comment: You're saying you're generating a URL like `http://api..../?data=http://....html?Name=John&Title...&size=400x400`?

Comment: Yes that is correct! I am looking for a way to put all this data in a single variable that i can pass in the querystring of my url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **URL encode** data with special characters you put into a URL:

```
var url = 'http://[myapp-url]/RecieveContact.html?Name=John%20Diggle&Title=IT%20Consultant&Organisation=testcomp&Telwork=0498553311&Telhome=&Gsm=0498553311&Email=testemail@mail.be&Website=www.testwebsite.be&Birthdate=24/04/97&Addresswork=&Addresshome=';

var query = 'http://.../?data=' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '&size=400x400';
```

This way you can represent characters like `&` inside a query string.

Comment: This was the fix i was looking for! Thank you for your time.